# onCreate method in fragment is not getting called when using the fragment in view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, tabview

This is my activity class calling fragments in oncreate method using viewpager and tablayout

```
    public class testScreen2 extends AppCompatActivity implements      View.OnClickListener {
    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    TextView mTextField;

    TimerTask  timerTask;

    Timer timer;

    int numberSubmitted=0;

    int s_id =20;


    ImageView ivSubmit;
    TextView tv;
    ViewPager pager;
    String jsonData;
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> options_answer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> options_answer_submitted = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    Button button;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    MyPageAdapter adapter;
    int[] type = {2, 3, 4, 9, 2};
    int size;
    static ArrayList<Integer> OPTION_COUNT_AGAIN= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> ID_LIST= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> TYPE= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> SUBQUESTION_OPTION_COUNT= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> mcq_id= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> section_question_id= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> yn_answer= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> yn_id= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> tf_id= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> tf_answer= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> comp_ques_id= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> subques_tf_ans= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> subques_yn_ans= new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> comp_subques_id= new ArrayList<Integer>();;

    static ArrayList<String> mcq= new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> tf= new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> question= new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> yn,comp_ques_head= new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String>  comp_subques= new ArrayList<String>(); // comp_subquestion;

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> options=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> subques_options=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();;

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> optionsId=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> CompSubquesOptionsIdArrayListSelected = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();


    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subques_options_id=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();;

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subques_options_answer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> optionsIdArrayListSelected = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> TYPE_SUB = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> optionsSubmitted = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> attempted = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int Length;


    static ArrayList<String> MCQ_SELECTED_OPTIONS = new ArrayList<String>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> MCQ_ATTEMPT_PREVIOUS = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static ArrayList<String> SUB_QUES_IN_SELECTED_OPTIONS= new ArrayList<String>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> SUB_QUES_IN_ATTEMPT_PREVIOUS = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> TF_CORRECT= new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> YN_CORRECT = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> TF_ATTEMPT_PREVIOUS = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> YN_ATTEMPT_PREVIOUS = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> COMP_TF_ATTEMPT_PREVIOUS = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> COMP_TF_CORRECT = new ArrayList<Integer>();

static ArrayList<Integer> COMP_YN_ATTEMPT_PREVIOUS = new ArrayList<Integer>();

static ArrayList<Integer> COMP_YN_CORRECT = new ArrayList<Integer>();



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_screen2);


            Log.d("Testing","In testscreen 2");
            ivSubmit=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        mTextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);

            ivSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
            button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.testscreen);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            Log.d("Debug", "Reached testscreen2");
            size = type.length;
            Intent intent = getIntent();

            if (options != null) {
                    Log.d("Debug", "Got arraylist options");
            }
            Length = intent.getIntExtra("Length", 0);

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

            for (int i = 0; i < question.size(); i++)   {
                    int a = i + 1;
                    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("" + a));
                Log.d("TYPE","TYPE is "+TYPE.get(i));
                Log.d("Debug","We have added tabnumber "+a);

            }



          tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);
            tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
            pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

            adapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(), TYPE, TYPE_SUB);

            pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tabLayout.getTabCount() - 1);

            // the number of "off screen" pages to keep loaded each side of the current page



            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
          tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


                    pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
```

}}

Now i am posting the code of FragmentPagerAdapter class also

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;
String[] options;
int[] quesType;
questionOptionBoth tab1;
true_false tab2;
yes_no_fragment tab3;
comprehension_tf tab4;
comprehension_yn tab5;
comprehension_mcq tab6;
//fragment_comprehension tab4;
ArrayList<Integer> TYPE, TYPE_SUB;
public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs, ArrayList<Integer> TYPE, ArrayList<Integer> TYPE_SUB) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    this.TYPE=TYPE;
    this.TYPE_SUB=TYPE_SUB;
}



@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    int type=TYPE.get(position);
    int type_sub=TYPE_SUB.get(position);
    if(type==2 && type_sub==0) {
        tab1 = questionOptionBoth.newInstance(position);
        Log.d("Fragment","We have created mcq fragment at position "+position );
        return tab1;
    }
    else if(type==3 && type_sub==0)
    {
        tab2 = true_false.newInstance(position);
        return tab2;
    }

    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}




@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

}

Now, the problem is fragment's oncreate method is not getting called but fragment is being instantiated. This works fine in devices running pre-lollipop versions of android but in lollipop and above some fragments are just instantiated but their lifecycle methods such as onCreate and onAttach are not calledI am also posting the code of fragment for reference.

```
   public class questionOptionBoth extends Fragment implements      MyRecyclerViewAdapter.MyInterface {


ImageView ivQuestion;
private MyRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
String ques;
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters

private int tabNumber;
public static final String TAB_NUMBER = "TAB_NUMBER";
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

ArrayList<String> optionsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<Integer> optionsIdArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<Integer> optionsIdArrayListSelected = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<Integer> optionsArrayListPrevSelected = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 LinearLayout linearQuestionOption;

String optionsMarked;


String[] optionPreviouslyMarked;


public static final questionOptionBoth newInstance(int tabNumber) {
   Log.d("DebugQO","We are in mcq fragment at tabnumber "+tabNumber);
    questionOptionBoth f = new questionOptionBoth();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle();

    bdl.putInt(TAB_NUMBER, tabNumber);

    f.setArguments(bdl);






    return f;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    Log.d("Attach","We are in onattach method");

    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    Log.d("Attach","We are in onattach method");
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.d("Pause","Onpause is called");
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   Log.d("Debug","We are in oncreate method at tabnumber "+tabNumber);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (getArguments() != null) {
        tabNumber = getArguments().getInt(TAB_NUMBER);
        Log.d("TabNumber","Tabnumber is "+tabNumber);


        optionsArrayList = ((testScreen2) getActivity()).getOptionsFromQues(tabNumber);

        optionsIdArrayList = ((testScreen2) getActivity()).getOptionIdsFromQues(tabNumber);

        optionsMarked=((testScreen2)getActivity()).get_MCQ_SELECTED_OPTIONS(tabNumber);

        if(optionsMarked==null||optionsMarked.equals("null"))
        {} else{
            optionPreviouslyMarked= optionsMarked.split(",");
        }

        if (optionsArrayList != null) {
            Log.d("Debug", "Got options list in oncreate method in fragment");
        }

        if (optionsIdArrayList != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < optionsIdArrayList.size(); i++) {
                optionsIdArrayListSelected.add(i, 0);
                optionsArrayListPrevSelected.add(i,0);
                Log.d("OptionIDArraylist","OPtionIDArrayList previously selected "+ i+" at tabnumber"+tabNumber+" is "+optionsArrayListPrevSelected.get(i));
            }



         if(optionsMarked==null||optionsMarked.equals("null"))
         {} else
         {
             Log.d("options marked", "options marked is not null");
             Log.d("options marked","options marked is "+optionsMarked);
             for(int z=0;z<optionPreviouslyMarked.length;z++)
             {


                    int position=optionsIdArrayList.indexOf(Integer.valueOf(optionPreviouslyMarked[z].trim()));


                 optionsIdArrayListSelected.set(position,Integer.valueOf(optionPreviouslyMarked[z].trim()));
                optionsArrayListPrevSelected.add(position, 1);
             }
         }




            ((testScreen2) getActivity()).CompSubquesOptionsIdArrayListSelected.add(tabNumber,null);

            ((testScreen2) getActivity()).optionsIdArrayListSelected.add(tabNumber, new ArrayList<Integer>(optionsIdArrayListSelected));

        }



        Log.d("Debug","The size in questionOptionBoth at tabNumber "+tabNumber+" is "+optionsIdArrayList.size());

        ques = ((testScreen2) getActivity()).getQues(tabNumber);

        // String[] quesParts = ques.split("#IM@Ge#B!n@RyD@T@#");
        // quesData = quesParts[0];
        // quesImage = quesParts[1];

        Log.d("Debug", "Got questions");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("tabbb","tab number is null");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    Log.d("DebugOncreateV","We are in oncreateview at tabnumber "+tabNumber);

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_option_both, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.option_recycler_view);
    Log.d("Debug", "Initialised recycler view");

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    Log.d("Debug", "Set the fixed size as true");

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

    Log.d("Debug", "Reached layout manager");

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(optionsArrayList, optionsIdArrayList, this,getContext(),optionsArrayListPrevSelected);


    Log.d("Debug", "Initialised adapter");

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Log.d("Debug", "Set adapter");

    linearQuestionOption=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearQuestionOption);







    return rootView;
}


public TextView addTextView()
{
    TextView tv= new TextView(getContext());
    // tv.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    FlowLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    //tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    return tv;
}

public ImageView addImageView()
{
    ImageView iv= new ImageView(getContext());
    // iv.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    FlowLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    return iv;
}


@Override
public void onClickCheckBox(int event, int position) {
    if (event == 1) {


        int id = optionsIdArrayList.get(position);

        ((testScreen2) getActivity()).optionsIdArrayListSelected.get(tabNumber).set(position, id);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "We have clicked " + position + " checkbox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        ((testScreen2) getActivity()).optionsIdArrayListSelected.get(tabNumber).set(position, 0);
    }
}
```